# Can ternary search trees be used for every word?

Tags: string, algorithm, data-structures, prefix-tree, ternary-search-tree

A node has three children, left, right, and middle, but what if those are occupied? Then what? And by a different character? If the root is 'b', and I try to insert cecil and dock, then what will I do?

Comment: It's unclear to me what you don't understand. `cecil` and `dock` are both greater than `b` so will go on the `right` sub-tree. Had they started with `b` they would have gone on the `middle` sub-tree. - And the answer to the question in your caption is Yes.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError If I insert "cecil" first, then wont the insertion of "dock" remove "cecil"?

Comment: No, "dock" will then go on "cecil"'s right link because 'd' > 'c'.

Comment: So it literally works like BST?

Comment: I don't know about "literally", but basically, yeah.